# MongoServerError:Authentication Failed on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I installed Mongodb on Ubuntu 22.04. I setup the admin on Mongodb using this line of code

```
test\> use admin
```

switched to db admin

```
admin\> db.createUser({user:"john", pwd:"alx", roles:\[{role:"root", db:"admin"}\]})

{ ok: 1 }
```

Enable MongoDB authentication inside `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` by adding this line of code

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

I then run this command

```
mongosh -u demo -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I got this error after typing alx as my password

> Enter password:
> Current Mongosh Log ID:   64af5b02457d8abc538e7e4f
> Connecting to:        mongodb://<credentials>@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&authSource=admin&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
> MongoServerError: Authentication failed

I try to login into the Mongodb database on authentication

Comment: I would suggest to edit the config file `/etc/mongod.conf` and [authorization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-security.authorization) there. And then you should not modify service file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` directly, it may be reverted at update of MongoDB. Better create a copy to `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` and modify this copy. See [Where do I put my systemd unit file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224992/where-do-i-put-my-systemd-unit-file)

Comment: You created user `john`, but you connect with user `demo`

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use correct user name

> mongosh -u demo -p --authenticationDatabase admin // error
>
> mongosh -u john -p --authenticationDatabase admin // correct

2. Please check mongo version, I think that the root role does not include any access to collections in previous version of 3.07. If it is previous version, you can use following command.

```
    use admin
    db.addUser( { user: "<username>",
              pwd: "<password>",
              roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                       "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                       "readWriteAnyDatabase"
    ] } )
```